# What is the difference between dist/**/* and dist?

Tags: json, npm, glob

In `package.json`, I've seen some people write

```json
"files": [
  "dist/**/*"
]
```

and others write

```json
"files": [
  "dist/"
]
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**These two expressions are of the same effect.**

`dist/**/*`: The double asterisks `dist/**` mean all folders (recursively) below `dist/`, and `*` matches any file and directories under each subfolder.

`dist/`: simply means all files and folders below `dist/`.

You can use this [glob test tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2F%2A%2A%2F%2A.js&matches=false&tests=%2F%2F%20This%20will%20match%20as%20it%20ends%20with%20%27.js%27&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld.js&tests=%2F%2F%20This%20won%27t%20match%21&tests=%2Ftest%2Fsome%2Fglobs) to test it out.